# Unable to serialize object using Serilog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serilog

I'm trying to serialize an object to JSON using serilog.This is the code that i use.I have integrated serilog using app insights sink.

```
_logger.LogInformation("myserilog {@submitImportJobRequest}", submitImportJobRequest);
```

The above code produces the following result

```
  submitImportJobRequest
    {"_typeTag":"SubmitImportJobRequest"}
```

But when i use JsonConvert,the object is serialized.**Also other objects are serialized using the same code.**

Comment: Can you show the complete Request class code?

Comment: Do you not need to ensure you have `"formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"`? It may be more helpful to provide your serilog configuration, NuGet packages etc in the question.